# Ruby post title to slug

Tags: ruby, string, lowercase, gsub

How should I convert a post title to a slug in Ruby?

The title can have any characters, but I only want the slug to allow `[a-z0-9-_]` (Should it allow any other characters?).

So basically:

- downcase all letters
- convert spaces to hyphens
- delete extraneous characters

Comment: * remove extra words if the title is longer than N words

Answer (score 89, accepted):

```
slug = title.downcase.strip.gsub(' ', '-').gsub(/[^\w-]/, '')
```

`downcase` makes it lowercase. The `strip` makes sure there is no leading or trailing whitespace. The first `gsub` replaces spaces with hyphens. The second `gsub` removes all non-alpha non-dash non-underscore characters (note that this set is very close to `\W` but includes the dash as well, which is why it's spelled out here).

Comment: Your character class could be expressed more concisely as `/[^\w-]/`.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I added some more complexity to account for . \ / and to remove multiple -'s in a row and remove them from the end: `slug = title.strip.downcase.gsub(/[\s\.\/\\]/, '-').gsub(/[^\w-]/, '').gsub(/[-_]{2,}/, '-').gsub(/^[-_]/, '').gsub(/[-_]$/, '')`. I stopped after realizing it's pretty darn complicated to get it perfect. Also, `tr` is faster than `gsub`, so it's better to do: `tr(' ', '-')` than `gsub(' ', '-')`.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale. There is a ruby method called String#squeeze that will convert all sequences of two or more of the passed character to one. So you could write the above as `slug = title.downcase.gsub('/[\s.\/_]/, ' ').squeeze(' ').strip.gsub(/[^\w-]/, '').tr(' ', '-')`. This first turns all whitespace, `.`, `/`, and '_' to spaces. Then it squeezes spaces (all sequences of 2 or more spaces become a single one), then it it strips spaces (removes leading and trailing spaces), then it converts the remaining spaces back to dashes.

Comment: As far as speed of `gsub` processing versus `tr`, you're really just talking processor cycles -- nanoseconds, really. Unless you are creating hundreds of thousands of posts per second, that speed difference will make absolutely no difference. What you should take into account is personal style and clarity of code. In this case, I `tr` may still better, but for those two reasons, not because it's faster.

Comment: Oh, and this is the answer for plain Ruby. If you are using Rails, you can do just do `slug = title.parameterize` as Mark Thomas pointed out. Even if you are not using rails, you can get the same support from the active support gem by doing: `require 'active_support'; $KCODE = 'UTF8';`

Comment: Oh and I just noticed that in my comment a few above, I put the things in the wrong order. It should have been: `slug = title.downcase.gsub('/[\s.\/_]/, ' ').squeeze(' ').strip.tr(' ', '-').gsub(/[^\w-]/, '')`

Comment: @Ben Lee, Thanks for your recommendation to use String#squeeze. However, the refactoring doesn't work exactly as I have it. E.g., it returns `"hello---world"` when `title = "hello - world"`, but I want it to return `"hello-world"`. Also, delete the single quote after the first opening parenthesis.

Comment: @Matt, I didn't actually test the code I posted, so there's probably a bug or two in there, but you get the idea, right? You can play around with `gsub`, `squeeze`, and `tr` to get the desired result. Or you can stick with what you already had that worked =).

Comment: @BenLee I think you should put the `gsub(/[^\w-]/, '')` part before you strip the string. That way this expression will handle strings like `' ? ? hello ? ? world ? ?'` correctly

Answer (score 108):

Is this Rails? (works in Sinatra)

```
string.parameterize
```

That's it. For even more sophisticated slugging, see [ActsAsUrl](https://github.com/rsl/stringex). It can do the following:

```
"rock & roll".to_url => "rock-and-roll"
"$12 worth of Ruby power".to_url => "12-dollars-worth-of-ruby-power"
"10% off if you act now".to_url => "10-percent-off-if-you-act-now"
"kick it en Français".to_url => "kick-it-en-francais"
"rock it Español style".to_url => "rock-it-espanol-style"
"tell your readers 你好".to_url => "tell-your-readers-ni-hao"
```

Comment: It's not Rails, but it looks like that gem will work with plain Ruby as well. Thanks! I like how it converts & to and, but I want it to convert / and . to -. It converts them to slash and dot, respectively. Also, in this case, to keep things simple, I'd rather not require extra gems. So, I updated my solution to `slug = title.strip.downcase.gsub(/(&|&amp;)/, ' and ').gsub(/[\s\.\/\\]/, '-').gsub(/[^\w-]/, '').gsub(/[-_]{2,}/, '-').gsub(/^[-_]/, '').gsub(/[-_]$/, '')`.

Comment: Does it produces ASCII slugs, as [pandoc does](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-ascii_identifiers)?

Comment: @somenxavier `parameterize` does just that. It comes from [ActiveSupport::Inflector](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/parameterize). If you view the source, you'll see the comment "`# Replace accented chars with their ASCII equivalents`"

Answer (score 7):

[to_slug](https://github.com/ludo/to_slug) is a great Rails plugin that handles pretty much everything, including funky characters, but its implementation is very simple. Chuck it onto **String** and you'll be sorted. Here's the source condensed down:

```
String.class_eval do
  def to_slug
    value = self.mb_chars.normalize(:kd).gsub(/[^\x00-\x7F]/n, '').to_s
    value.gsub!(/[']+/, '')
    value.gsub!(/\W+/, ' ')
    value.strip!
    value.downcase!
    value.gsub!(' ', '-')
    value
  end
end
```

Comment: @JamieRumbelow- Your sample code had an error. you need to explicitely return `value`, because .gsub! returns nil when no substitutions are performed (e.g. `"test".to_slug` would return nil). I fixed the code for you.

Answer (score 3):

I've used this gem.It's simple but helpful.

https://rubygems.org/gems/string_helpers

Answer (score 0):

I like FriendlyId, the self-professed "Swiss Army Bulldozer" of creating slugs. https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: With this plugin, how do you call a method that'd slug your string ?